# "Run Unit Tests" option is not there in VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I am watching a video tutorial for unit testing. In that tutorial, when the lecturer clicks a right-click on Unit test class, one of the options there is "Run Unit Tests" whereas I am not getting that option.

[image]

Here are the options my VS showing:

[image]

Another thing is, when he uses the name of a class / method which does not exist, a bulb appears on the left side. This also does not appear in my VS.

[image]

P.S.

1. I am using VS-2013, win 7 64-bit
2. I cannot contact the tutorial maker otherwise could have asked him directly

Comment: Looks like he's running Resharper. https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Run Unit Tests, Debug Unit Tests are present due to an Extension that is Installed named Resharper, you can download this on a free 30 day trial.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/

Edit: 29/10/2017 - Visual Studio 2017
now provides live unit testing, whilst right clicking in a testable class a Live Unit Testing option appears, there is also a Test option across the toolbar that allows you additional unit test options such as debugging, running and live unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on VS2017 w/ an old version of ReSharper (I was on 2017.2.2) and using .NET Core, update to the latest version via Resharper -> Help -> Check for Updates. Right-click "Run Unit Tests" works for me again on 2018.1.